# smb (windows share links) open protocol change

Tags: smb

Is it possible to instruct my windows 8.1 machine to open links like these:
 smb://c:\path to some folder\
in windows explorer?
Right now, Internet Explorer automatically comes up in response to a request to open smb:// link and says No apps are installed for this type of link (smb) - [Look for an app in the Store]

(The reason I have this problem is because I use mediawiki on my machine and have links to folders and files on some pages. I'd like to be able to click them from any computer on my network and be able to see the file/folder right away).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Suppose you have a link like:

> `smb://a.b.com/public/`

In windows you can open that in the file explorer this way:

> `\\a.b.com\public\`